# Implementing 3D Page transition cube for different pages

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to add 3D flipping transition in between two pages. when searching for that i got this link.
http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Animated-3D-Cube-Slider-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

But that plug in is for flipping between divs in the same page.

I wonder is there any way to make the same animation between two different pages?

Thank you

Comment: Thats how you would do it.. Using div's, not loading a completely new page as thats what the browser does for you.

Comment: i wanted to know is there any method to implement the same/similar with different pages.. ? @Ruddy

Comment: I would say no, not if your thinking about loading a completely new page. Moving off the page would destroy the effect.

Comment: thanks for the tip anyway

Comment: I dont really see a need for a new page, using div's should serve you well. And your welcome.

Comment: [smoothState.js](http://weblinc.github.io/jquery.smoothState.js/index.html) might help with animating between pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use "iframe" to display each page in a cube.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp
For this example in "div" tag you can use:

```
<div class="cube">
    <div class="face one"><iframe src="example.html" /></div>
    <div class="face two"><iframe src="example_2.html" /></div>
    <div class="face three"><iframe src="example_3.html" /></div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: i just found it myself. thanks a lot for helping me out. @Masoud